# Advice on study design involving longitudinal clusters and measurements

Tags: clustering, panel-data, observational-study, research-design

I'm conducting an analysis on several hundred thousand individuals to understand if there are longitudinal differences in an outcome across clusters of the individuals. My outcome is healthcare cost (measured longitudinally) and clusters are groups of individuals with similar longitudinal trajectories of weight. Here's my setup:

**Cluster creation**
I split my sample into two - a development sample and a holdout sample. In the development sample, I performed the cluster analysis (specifically a growth mixture model, with longitudinal weight as the outcome) to estimate latent clusters of individuals with similar longitudinal weight trajectories.

**Cluster assignment**
Using the holdout sample (i.e. the sample not used for cluster creation), I applied the final model and predicted class assignments for each individual. Specifically, for each individual's longitudinal weight measurements, the model predicts the most likely class membership. I then collect longitudinal cost information for each individual in the holdout sample.

**Question**
Using the holdout sample, is it statistically valid to conduct inference that looks at the relationship between the predicted class assignments and longitudinal cost outcome? My concerns are two-fold:

1. An individual's longitudinal weight measurements will be informative of that person's longitudinal health care costs (e.g. weight at 3 months might influence healthcare costs at 5 months, which might influence weight at 8 months), but a person's predicted weight class is assumed to be predetermined and "fixed". Essentially the predicted class is some transformation of a person's longitudinal weight measurements, but is assumed to be baseline to the longitudinal cost outcomes.
2. There are recent works by Daniela Witten's group from UWash regarding double-dipping (generating a null hypothesis based on some data and testing hypotheses based on the same data). They suggest in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.02936.pdf) (in the context of hierarchical clustering) that sample splitting may still lead to double dipping as labeling the holdout/test set is the same as using the data to generate a null hypothesis. Inference on the holdout set would then lead to double dipping and potential type I error inflation.

Any thoughts on the validity of this design?